# How to point my code path to Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

```
from azure.ai.ml import Input, command
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Data, CommandJob
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes

# in this example we
my_job_inputs = {
    "input_data": Input(
        path='***',
        type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER
    )
}

job = command(
    code="****", # local path where the code is stored
    command='python main.py --input_folder ${{inputs.input_data}}',
    inputs=my_job_inputs,
    environment="test-env2",
    compute="compute-instance"                                                      
)

#submit the command job
returned_job = ml_client.create_or_update(job)
#get a URL for the status of the job
returned_job.services["Studio"].endpoint
```

For the code path I want to point it to Azure blob storage, since my code is uploaded there, but if I use the location of the blob storage I get:

```
ValidationException: /home/xmask/azure/azureml-blobstore-88acaeac-5f0c-40d5-852a-b152622f94b6/UI/wITP/05-26-2022_34567_UTC not found, local path must point to a file or directory. Path must follow proper formatting for datastore, job or run uri's.
```

Any ideas how I can point the code path to Azure blob storage?

Comment: In below answer i have given for an image, but for code, you need to read the content.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it.

1. Create a container & upload your blob. Keep its access level as
   [image]

Then Click on the blob, There will be a URL. Use that to access the image/file.

2. If you want to go with the secure way,without exposing the container as public. Use the SAS token.We can enable the SAS token for the respective blob only with specified long term validity. So the **Image URL + SAS token** will create a valid image URL. Generate it for specified long term / short term. Use the **Blob SAS URL** as the Image URL.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, I am still receiving this below error:
```HttpResponseError: (ServiceError) Received 500 from a service request
Code: ServiceError
Message: Received 500 from a service request
Target: PUT https://project.vienna-centralindia.svc/content/v2.0/subscriptions/61a26795-3922-404d-a23f-c114e86b801f/resourceGroups/automl/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/automl/snapshots/uri
Exception Details: (InternalServerError)```

Could you help me with it @lokanath das ?